# Polynomially many times launch $NL$ machine - is it in $NL$? On example of ACYCLIC

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Lets consider $$ACYCLIC = \{\langle G \rangle | G \text{ is acyclic}\}$$
We are going to prove that $ACYCLIC\in NL$. I know that the easiest approach for this task is to use the fact that $coNL=NL$. However, I wonder if correct answer is following approach:

The idea is to check each existence of each length of cycle. Let $n$ will be number of cycles.

```
    for l = 1..n
       is_cycle = non-deterministally check if there exists cycle of length l 
       if (is_cycle == "yes")
          then return "no"
    return "yes"// graph is acyclic because there is no cycle of length 1..n
```

Is it correct approach in $NL$?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement this part in NL:

> nondeterministically check something
>
> if yes, return no

Consider the following analogy: the language $K$ of all Turing machines that halt is recursively enumerable but its negation isn't. That is, $K$ is accepted by some nondeterministic Turing machine, but its negation cannot be accepted by any nondeterministic Turing machine. This means that you *provably* cannot implement the following using nondeterminism:

> nondeterministically check if the given Turing machine halts
>
> if yes, return no

Your idea suffers from the same problem.

---

Here is a different angle. The following algorithm checks nondeterministically that $s$ and $t$ are connected:

> guess a path $w$ from $s$ to $t$
>
> verify that $w$ is a path; if so, output yes, otherwise, output no

The semantics of this algorithm are as follows:

1. If there is some witness that causes the algorithm to output yes, then the input is a yes input.
2. If all witnesses cause the algorithm to output no, then the input is a no input.

What you are trying to do is as follows:

> guess a path $w$ from $s$ to $t$
>
> verify that $w$ is a path; if so, output no, otherwise, output yes

All inputs are yes instances in this case, since there is always some witness $w$ that *isn't* a path from $s$ to $t$.

In order to check that there is no path, you would have to do the following:

> go over all possible paths $w$ from $s$ to $t$
>
> if none of them works, output yes, otherwise, output no

Unfortunately, this doesn't describe a nondeterministic Turing machine.

Comment: I think that it would be great to create a reference question concerning how NDTM and DTM work, different but equivalent models, wrong designs of NDTMs, etc..

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: In other words, we can't negate answer of nondeterministal machine, yeah ? However, when NTM is treated as oracle that we can negate its answer. yeah >?

Comment: That's right. When used as an oracle, it's like a function call and we can do whatever we want with the output.

Comment: Oh, so $w$ is witness. The good idea is always assign result of NTM to $w$ and then conisder when $w$ can be accepted and when rejected.